VueJS User cant alter checkbox state
I have the following script which use to work perfectly fine.
<div id="inspectionList" class="row m-0 p-0" v-if="app.getOption('InspectionChecklists')">
<div v-for="(checklist, index) in (JSON.parse(app.getOption('InspectionChecklists')))[app.store.AddAsset_Module][1]">
     <div class="col-12 m-2 p-1 mb-2" v-for="(inspection, index) in checklist">

          <input
          type="checkbox"
          v-bind:name="index"
          v-bind:class="'form-check-input'"
          v-bind:id="index"
          v-bind:value="index"
          v-model="app.store.AddAsset_Type_inspections"
          style="height:30px; width:30px; accent-color: #5873fe;">
           <label v-bind:for="index" style="position:relative; top:-5px">{{inspection.n}}</label>
     </div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="debugInfo"  v-if="app.store.debug">
Debug: {{ app.store.debug }}
<span>Checked names: {{ app.store.AddAsset_Type_inspections }}</span>
</div>

The script generates a list of checkboxes, and automatically checks any of them that are in the array store in app.store.AddAsset_Type_inspections
app.store.AddAsset_Type_inspections has the following data for example:
Checked names: [
259,
9,
68,
45,
41,
264,
55,
13,
262,
271,
270,
1,
23,
260,
3,
44,
63,
24,
56,
261,
19,
30,
18,
31,
17,
2,
14,
29,
46,
36,
26,
8,
25,
33,
35,
28,
282,
52,
50,
51,
49,
53
]
For some reason, after updating VueJS core library to 3.4.27, the checkboxes automatically check as needed - however users cant manually check or uncheck any of the check boxes.
Things i've tried:

I added a standard <input type="checkbox" name="test"> checkbox, and it is possible to check and uncheck this without an issue.

If I remove v-model="app.store.AddAsset_Type_inspections" so that checkboxes don't automatically get checked, then it's possible for a user to check and uncheck any of the boxes without an issue.

I've looked for any console errors, and no errors are generated


Heres a screenshot of the checkboxes which shows the auto-checked ones, and additionally, the highlight after clicking a checkbox that shows the checkbox isn't disabled.


dunno what you upgraded from, but at a wild guess that some immutibilty rules likely got added between versions. I would suggest first try using a local state for the checkbox component rather than reading and writing directly to the global appState.

Have you checked the Vue devtools to find out if you maybe have the state populated already (hence why they are checked)? From which version have you migrated from? Did you make a differential between any git commits to be sure that this is coming from Vue? Have you checked some of the latest releases to see if something might have changed regarding checkboxes? Can you also double-check the checking state with a test ref, just to see if v-model can properly check the box and that it's not something else than a state issue?
